# filtering a column list from a term starting from the back

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataset:

```
emails1 = ['abc@gmail.com', "ddd@hotmail.com", "www@outlook.com"]
emails2 = ['data@hello.com', "abc@gmail.com", 'data@gmail.com', "abc@gmail.com"]
emails3 =  ["abc@gmail.com", 'lll@hello.com']

terms = ['@gmail.com', 'data', 'ddd@']

df = pd.DataFrame([emails1, emails2, emails3])

df["emails"] = df.apply(lambda x: list([x[0],
                        x[1],
                        x[2],
                        x[3]]),axis=1)

df = df.iloc[: , 4:]
df
    emails
0   [abc@gmail.com, ddd@hotmail.com, www@outlook.com, None]
1   [data@hello.com, abc@gmail.com, data@gmail.com, abc@gmail.com]
2   [abc@gmail.com, lll@hello.com, None, None]
```

I need to be able to find the first item of each list (starting from the back) that is from the terms array,
so my out put wold be another column:

```
    emails                                                             email wanted
0   [abc@gmail.com, ddd@hotmail.com, www@outlook.com, None]            [ddd@hotmail.com]
1   [data@hello.com, abc@gmail.com, data@gmail.com, abc@gmail.com]     [abc@gmail.com]
2   [abc@gmail.com, lll@hello.com, None, None]                         [abc@hotmail.com]
```

I tried this for each of the terms and combined the result, but does not work:

df["emails"].apply(lambda x:[i for i in x if '@gmail.com' in i])

Is there a good way of doing this?

Comment: can you break down the logic? It's unclear

Comment: I am trying to find the first email (when the list is backwards), which is in the "terms" array and create a new column using that

Comment: so you mean any terms for each row? There is no match row1 -> @gmail.com, row2 -> data, etc.? That's why I asked you to break down the logic to be explicit

Comment: so for row1, it would start reading backwards and searching for any value in terms -> e.g, it would look at the first item which is "None", this is not in the terms so ignore, and then "www@outlook.com", this is not in terms to move on to next. then it sees that "ddd@hotmail.com" is in the terms to that would be the new column value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact logic is unclear, but you need a list comprehension:

```
import re
regex = re.compile('|'.join(map(re.escape, terms)))
# r'@gmail\.com|data|ddd@'

df['wanted'] = [next((x for x in l[::-1] if x and regex.search(x)), None)
                for l in df['emails']]
```

output:

```
                                              emails           wanted
0  [abc@gmail.com, ddd@hotmail.com, www@outlook.c...  ddd@hotmail.com
1  [data@hello.com, abc@gmail.com, data@gmail.com...    abc@gmail.com
2         [abc@gmail.com, lll@hello.com, None, None]    abc@gmail.com
```